# Android Flexbox setFlexBasisPercent not working

Tags: android, android-flexboxlayout

I'm using android's now layout - FlexboxLayout.
When I add some view to FlexboxLayout programmatically,
FlexboxLayout.setWidth( int ) is working but FlexboxLayout.setFlexBasisPercent( float ) not.
Why!!! I can't understand.
Here is my code.

[image]

------------- I Find Answer!!! 2017/07/30/11:59

my mistake is that

```
lp.setFlexBasisPercent(10)
```

FlexboxLayout.setFlexBasisPercent(**0.1f**) was right!!!

Comment: You should post the code `as-is`, not the picture of the code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation on Flexbox is scarce, but from what im gathering, the parent element has to have a defined width/height in order for that to work. Here is a quote.

> This attribute is only effective when the parent's length is definite
>   (MeasureSpec mode is MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
>   https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

Comment: Then should I get width of parentview of flexboxlayout , and then FlexboxLayout.setWidth( the width of parentView );

Comment: I think whatever root element that you are attaching the flexbox  to needs to have a defined width/height. At least thats what im gathering from the docs.