# Android Flex Layout set flexBasisPercent?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin, android-flexboxlayout

I'm using Google's `FlexBoxLayout` for a project, and I cant make `flexBasisPercent` work for the view that I defined progmatically. The root view is declared as,

```
val root = FlexboxLayout(context)
root.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

root.flexWrap = FlexWrap.WRAP
root.flexDirection = FlexDirection.COLUMN
root.justifyContent = JustifyContent.FLEX_START
root.alignItems = AlignItems.FLEX_START
root.alignContent = AlignContent.FLEX_START
```

and the Child view as,

```
 val child = FlexboxLayout(context)
 val childParams = FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams(FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FlexboxLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
 childParams.flexGrow = 0.5f
 childParams.flexBasisPercent = 0.5f
 childParams.setMargins(16,16,16,16)
 child.layoutParams = childParams

 val info = TextView(context)
 info.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
 info.text = "12"
 child.addView(info)
 root.addView(child).
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to these for help:

> [Android Flexbox setFlexBasisPercent not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384860/android-flexbox-setflexbasispercent-not-working)

or

> https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout/issues/506